# Why is the Build trigger complaining about Webhooks missing

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-devops-pipelines

It is time we enabled the Continuous Integration of the build pipeline, so when I went to do just that, i am seeing something strange...

The trigger appears to be enabled? yet theres a message suggesting webhooks are missing to the repo and need to be restored. When i click restore, it fails!

> The remote repository’s webhooks are missing or incorrect.

[image: rest]

```
An error occurred while restoring the trigger’s webhook: Could not recreate the subscription. An error was encountered while creating the existing subscription: Unable to configure a service on the selected Bitbucket repository. Bitbucket returned the error 'Your credentials lack one or more required privilege scopes.'.
```

I asked the admin of the repo to try restoring it because i thought maybe this is a permissions issue, and even he got the error...

This is what the repository settings page shows for both myself and the repo developer/admin...

[image: repo page]

Do we have to add a webhook manually on bitbucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging the issue further with the developer, it appears the app password we created in bitbucket may not have had the "Webhooks" option enabled.

Unfortunately, we cannot edit app passwords in Bitbucket, which is a bad constraint but whatever.
We ended up just [creating a new app password](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/), and enabled Webhooks permissions this time, then i updated the service connection with this new app password, and wala, it worked!

[image: apppass]